# Select All on join query SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to select all from a join query, I want to echo out all data from the datapackages table that belongs to a user instead of joining each column?

Here is my sql query:

```sql
SELECT ip_address, SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, SUM(download_bytes) as 
download_bytes, 
        sum(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes, package_id, 
username 
        FROM 
        (
           (SELECT ipaccounting.src_address as ip_address, 
SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes, 0 as download_bytes, 
            users.username, datapackages.package_id 
            FROM ipaccounting
            join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address
            join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
            WHERE dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
            GROUP BY src_address)
        UNION ALL 
           (SELECT ipaccounting.dst_address as ip_address, 0 AS 
upload_bytes, SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) as download_bytes, 
            users.username, datapackages.package_id
            FROM ipaccounting 
            join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
            join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
            WHERE src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
            GROUP BY dst_address)
        ) a 
        GROUP BY ip_address 
        ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address)
```

My complete code:

```
<?php
//Include needed files
require ("config.php");
require ("includes/routeros_api.class.php");
include ("includes/formatbytes.php");

//Connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($SQLserver, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, 
$SQLdatabase);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


//Convert IP Addresses
$IPRangeStart = ip2long($IPRangeStart);
$IPRangeEnd = ip2long($IPRangeEnd);

//Query database
$query = "
    SELECT ip_address, SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, 
SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes, 
        sum(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes, package_id, 
username 
        FROM 
        (
           (SELECT ipaccounting.src_address as ip_address, 
SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes, 0 as download_bytes, 
            users.username, datapackages.package_id 
            FROM ipaccounting
            join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address
            join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
            WHERE dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
            GROUP BY src_address)
        UNION ALL 
           (SELECT ipaccounting.dst_address as ip_address, 0 AS 
upload_bytes, SUM(ipaccounting.bytes) as download_bytes, 
            users.username, datapackages.package_id
            FROM ipaccounting 
            join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
            join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
            WHERE src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND 
INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254')  
            GROUP BY dst_address)
        ) a 
        GROUP BY ip_address 
        ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address)
    ";


//Execute query
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


//Display IP information
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>IP Address</th><th>Upload</th><th>Download</th><th>Total</th>
<th>Username</th><th>Data Package</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ip_address = $row['ip_address'];
        $upload_bytes = $row['upload_bytes'];
        $download_bytes = $row['download_bytes'];
        $total_bytes = ($upload_bytes + $download_bytes);

        $total_bytes = formatBytes($total_bytes);
        $upload_bytes = formatBytes($upload_bytes);
        $download_bytes = formatBytes($download_bytes);

        $username = $row['username'];
        $datapackage = $row['package_id'];

    echo "<tr><td>".$ip_address."</td><td>".$upload_bytes."</td>
<td>".$download_bytes."</td><td>".$total_bytes."</td><td>".$username."</td>
<td>".$datapackage."</td</tr>";

    //API MikroTik
    /*$API = new RouterosAPI();

    $API->debug = true;

    if ($API->connect($RouterIP, $APIusername, $APIpassword)) {

       $API->comm("/queue/simple/add", array(
        "target-address="=> "10.10.10.16");

       $API->disconnect();

    }*/



} 

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I need to echo out IP Address | Upload | Download | Total | Threshold | Download Speed  | Upload Speed | Data Limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot remember if this is the correct answer as I asked the question a long time ago but if I can remember correctly, the answer I was looking for is something similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    devices.*, 
    device_info.* 
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN device_info ON devices.id = device_info.device_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ip_address, 
SUM(IF(ipaccounting.src_address != NULL, ipaccounting.bytes, 0)) as upload_bytes, 
SUM(IF(ipaccounting.dst_address != NULL, ipaccounting.bytes, 0)) as download_bytes, 
sum(ipaccounting.bytes) as totalbytes, 
package_id, username 
FROM ipaccounting
join users on users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.src_address OR users.ipaddress = ipaccounting.dst_address
join datapackages on datapackages.package_id = users.datapackage
WHERE ipaccounting.dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
AND ipaccounting.src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
GROUP BY src_address,dst_address ORDER BY INET_ATON(src_address),INET_ATON(dst_address)
```

For more accurate query please post table structure and sample data.

Comment: This does not answer my question and nor does it help me at all, If I test the query you provided then I get upload bytes 0 and download bytes 0

Comment: That's because ipaccounting.src_address != NULL condition is always true, you have to change it according to your dataset.  I assumed that src_address is NULL when dst_address has some value.